# Did 9.1.3 FluentValidation update ruin validators mocks?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I updated to 9.1.3 version of the package and now my validator mocks do not work.

Somehow code runs no matter whether `.Validate()` returns `true` or `false`.

Here is the code for the validator mock:

```cs
validatorMock
    .Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<IValidationContext>()).IsValid)
    .Returns(false);

    Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() => command.Execute(request), "Position field validation error");
    repositoryMock.Verify(repository => repository.EditPosition(It.IsAny<DbPosition>()), Times.Never);
```

And here is the test failing:

```
Message: 
      Position field validation error
      Expected: <FluentValidation.ValidationException>
      But was:  null
```

Validator.cs:

```cs
public class SampleValidator : AbstractValidator<Position>
    {
        public SampleValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(position => position.Name)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MaximumLength(80)
                .WithMessage("Position name is too long");

            RuleFor(position => position.Description)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MaximumLength(350)
                .WithMessage("Position description is too long");
        }
    }
```

Dependency Injection:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Position>, SampleValidator>();
```

Usage:

```cs
public class SampleCommand : ISampleCommand
    {
        private readonly IValidator<Position> validator;
        private readonly ISampleRepository repository;
        private readonly IMapper<Position, DbPosition> mapper;

        public SampleCommand(
            [FromServices] IValidator<Position> validator,
            [FromServices] ISampleRepository repository,
            [FromServices] IMapper<Position, DbPosition> mapper)
        {
            this.validator = validator;
            this.repository = repository;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public bool Execute(Position request)
        {
            validator.ValidateAndThrow(request);

            var position = mapper.Map(request);

            return repository.EditPosition(position);
        }
    }
```

Validator Mocks in test:

```cs
private Mock<IValidator<EditPositionRequest>> validatorMock;
...
validatorMock = new Mock<IValidator<Position>>();
```

**UPDATE**

Before the update, all tests were running perfectly. Now they're ruined and I have to install the previous version.

Comment: Haha. Really, the update ruins the tests: I downgraded to 9.0.1 and tests run just fine.
Exceptions are thrown as usual.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White 
Added Validator.cs and its mocks. Need something else?

Really, it's simple to reproduce. Create any kind of validator, use it somewhere, then try to mock it in Tests. True or False: the code will run somehow.

Interesting enough, validators do work by themselves! There's so much weirdness around it, but I can 100% guarantee that 9.0.1 version works and the 9.1.3 version does not.

However, I'm ready to fulfill all needed data to prove this. I'm just new to SO

Comment: I'm the author of FluentValidation - I responded to a similar question about this on the FluentValidation issue tracker here: https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1485 Essentially, yes, if you were attempting to mock validators and test this way before this will no longer work. When you indicate an exception should be thrown, this now happens from *inside* the validator instance, so if you're mocking the validator this will no longer run. Ideally you shouldn't be mocking validators, but treating them as black boxes. Please see the issue linked to for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Yes, 9.1 changed how throwing validation exceptions is handled.

Some context:

Validator classes return a `ValidationResult` with an `IsValid` boolean property. The `ValidateAndThrow` extension method checks this property, and throws an exception if `IsValid` is false. If you mocked the validator, you could still use the "real" `ValidateAndThrow` extension method on your mock to throw an exception if your mock returned an invalid validation result.

In FluentValidation 9.1, the logic for throwing the exception was moved out of the extension method and into the validator class itself, in the `RaiseValidationException`. This was done so that the logic for throwing the exception could be customized (by overriding this method) which couldn't be done before when it was an extension method.

```cs
// This is the ValidateAndThrow method definition versions older than 9.1
public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance) {
  var result = validator.Validate(instance);
  
  if (!result.IsValid) {
    throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
  }
}

// This is the ValidateAndThrowMethod in 9.1 and newer
public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance) {
  validator.Validate(instance, options => {
    options.ThrowOnFailures();
  });
}
```

For runtime use, this doesn't make a difference - the exception is still thrown (unless you've overridden the method to prevent this).

However, this had the side effect that if you were relying on the exception being thrown by the extension method rather than the validator, this will have an undesirable result. This is really only the case when mocking the validator. Now when you create a mock, the exception won't be thrown because the mock doesn't behave as a real validator.

My recommendation with FluentValidation has always been "don't mock validators", instead treat them as black boxes and supply real validator instances with valid/invalid input for testing purposes - this leads to much less brittle tests in the long run. However, I'm also aware that it may not be possible to rewrite your tests in this way if you already have lots of them.

As a workaround, you can mock the overload of `Validate` that takes a `ValidationContext` and check the context for the `ThrowOnFailures` property, and have your mock throw the exception if this is set to true.

However, be aware that if you do this you could run into a situation where your mock behaves one way and the real validator behaves differently (if its RaiseValidationException message has been overridden).

As this is a breaking change, shouldn't it have been made in a major version? Ideally yes, this was my bad as I didn't foresee this particular use case.

Edit: Here's an example of creating a mock that checks the `ThrowOnFailures` property. The example uses the Moq library, but the same concept will apply to other mocking libraries too.

```cs
private static Mock<IValidator<T>> CreateFailingMockValidator<T>() {
  var mockValidator = new Mock<IValidator<T>>();

  var failureResult = new ValidationResult(new List<ValidationFailure>() {
    new ValidationFailure("Foo", "Bar")
  });

  // Setup the Validate/ValidateAsync overloads that take an instance.
  // These will never throw exceptions.
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.Validate(It.IsAny<T>()))
    .Returns(failureResult).Verifiable();
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<T>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(failureResult);

  // Setup the Validate/ValidateAsync overloads that take a context.
  // This is the method called by ValidateAndThrow, so will potentially support throwing the exception.
  // Setup method invocations for with an exception and without.
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.Validate(It.Is<ValidationContext<T>>(context => context.ThrowOnFailures)))
    .Throws(new ValidationException(failureResult.Errors));
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.ValidateAsync(It.Is<ValidationContext<T>>(context => context.ThrowOnFailures), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Throws(new ValidationException(failureResult.Errors));

  // If ThrowOnFailures is false, return the result.
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.Validate(It.Is<ValidationContext<T>>(context => !context.ThrowOnFailures)))
    .Returns(failureResult).Verifiable();
  mockValidator.Setup(p => p.ValidateAsync(It.Is<ValidationContext<T>>(context => !context.ThrowOnFailures), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(failureResult);

  return mockValidator;
}
```

Comment: Did not expect to get an answer from the library author!
Thank you for your clarification on this. Alright, I see what's been changed but could you please provide an example of how to mock this properly? I can't seem to understand the process.
If previously we set whether validation Result is valid or not, now I don't know what and how to mock.

I tried your suggestion to check ThrowOnFailures, but it defaults to false and I can't set it to true like "Returns(false)", like I've been doing with IsValid property.

Comment: Hi @mekk1t I've updated my answer to include some sample code for checking ThrowOnFailures. Essentially you have to setup the mock to check if ThrowOnFailures is true, and if so call "Throws(new ValidationException())" rather than "Returns(result)".

Comment: I am truly stunned by this. Thank you so much! Will implement that and try to explain to the team that it is the way to go. :)

Comment: hey, Jeremy. @JeremySkinner
I'm revisiting this question and I want to say you were right. Absolutely.
We should in no way ever mock validators or any other private dependencies. V. Khorikov's book on Unit Testing got me thinking on that. TDD is so messed up, that's insane!

Thank you again for the attention. For me as a newbie developer back a few months this was a surprising moment. Now I just feel gratitude for the friendly C# and developer community. Cheers! 
Thanks again for the answer (and the library update. The lib is really cool!)